# Is it considered bad practise to not have security headers on my API?

Tags: http-headers

I have two websites at the moment.

- admin.example.com
- api.example.com

The "admin" one has all the security headers recommended by https://securityheaders.io.

The "api" has none, which is deliberate. I know that this application will only serve JSON and is a relatively simple API.

Is this bad practise? Do the headers protect against any issues for a API-only site?

I already have HSTS headers set in both scenarios, which is obviously important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on requiremt of API ,if API is transactional then go with HSTS headers else don't .If API is not containing sensitive data then don't use it .

**HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) :**

> Let’s say you have a website named api.example.com  and you installed
>   an SSL/TLS certificate and migrated from HTTP to HTTPS. But this isn’t
>   where the work stops. What if your website is still available over
>   HTTP? It would be utterly pointless, right? Many website admins
>   migrate to HTTPS and then forget about it without realizing this. This
>   is where HSTS enters the picture. If a site is equipped with HTTPS,
>   the server forces the browser to communicate over secure HTTPS. This
>   way, the possibility of an HTTP connection is eliminated entirely.